# Area under a curve with limits based on stationary points

Tags: calculus

I have a problem where i need to integrate an area under a specific range of a curve. The curve will look something like the sketch below and I need to calculate the area that is shaded.

My problem is I dont know a good mathematical method to do so.

My method would be to compute the stationary points by hand and then set these as the limits.

However my problem need to be done about once a second in matlab and i dont know any mathematical methods to do this

Any ideas?

[image: area under curve with limits]